# Error (#1093) in MySQL update query

Tags: mysql

i have a MySQL query as follows

```
UPDATE `bills_receivables` as P 
SET P.days = (
    SELECT DATEDIFF(CURDATE(),STR_TO_DATE(date, '%Y-%m-%d')) AS DAYS 
    FROM `bills_receivables`
) ;
```

but when run this an error is occurred like

```
#1093 - You can't specify target table 'P' for update in FROM clause
```

what is the mistake made by me.

Answer (score 1):

You can't specify the table that you are updating in the from clause of the select that helps you select those rows like that. The subselect is invalid anyway, because it would return multiple fields and multiple rows, both are not valid, since you are comparing that query result to P.DAYS.

And I don't think you need to make it that complex. This should suffice:

```
UPDATE `bills_receivables` as P 
SET P.days = DATEDIFF(CURDATE(),STR_TO_DATE(P.date, '%Y-%m-%d'))
```